# Prototype chain callback

Tags: javascript

I have a Object that calls some async functions, using a prototype chain:

```
function Wow() {
  this.myAsyncFunction();
}

Wow.prototype.myAsyncFunction = function() {
  // Once my async function is complete, I fire a callback
  this.completed(); // Does not work
}
```

I would like to use it like this:

```
var wow = new Wow();
wow.completed = function() {
  alert('Awesome');
}
```

Here is a code snippet I created to simulate a my idea.

```js
function Wow() {
    this.ok = document.getElementById('ok');
    this.wait();
}

Wow.prototype.wait = function() {
    this.ok.innerHTML = "Waiting..."
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        this.completed();
    }, 1000);
}


var wow = new Wow();
wow.completed = function() {
    wow.ok.innerHTML = "Compelted";
};
```

```css
#ok {
    font-size: 28px;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="ok"></div>
```

I spent more than a hour searching google and StackOverflow for a solution, but I'm finding difficulties to even search for it.

Comment: Put the actual context in the question. The problem you have in the external code is completely different to the problem you have in the code here.

Comment: Whether you use the prototype or not doesn't really matter. It's about getting the wrong `this` context for the invocation of your callback.

Comment: Sometimes you focus so much on *what you think* is the problem, that you loose sight of the real problem. I'm sorry for the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `this` isn't inherited among nested functions.

This works:

```
Wow.prototype.wait = function() {
    this.ok.innerHTML = "Waiting...";
    var that = this;
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        that.completed();
    }, 1000);
}
```

```js
function Wow() {
    this.ok = document.getElementById('ok');
    this.wait();
}

Wow.prototype.wait = function() {
    this.ok.innerHTML = "Waiting...";
    var that = this;
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        that.completed();
    }, 1000);
}


var wow = new Wow();
wow.completed = function() {
    wow.ok.innerHTML = "Compelted";
};
```

```css
#ok {
    font-size: 28px;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="ok"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `wait` function a little bit, `this` is not available when `setTimeOut` runs the code, because that code is out of context `this`:

```
Wow.prototype.wait = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.ok.innerHTML = "Waiting..."
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        self.completed();
    }, 1000);
}
```

Working sample -- http://jsfiddle.net/4xcjhe8d/2/